# Webpack import statements inside a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm using Webpack(2.2) to create nested import.

```
//This is a separate npm package called 'input-field'
//InputField index.js
export default {}; //exports empty object


//This is a another separate npm package called 'todo-list'
//TodoList index.js, runs npm install --save input-field
import InputField from 'input-field';
export default {}; //export empty object


//finally this is the project that uses todo-list
//WebpackEntryPoint, runs npm install --save todo-list;
import TodoList from 'todo-list
```

so here's what happens :(when trying to build using webpack)
1. webpack resolves todo-list as expected.
2. webpack fails to resolve 'input-field'

So my questions :

How does Webpack resolve imports when building the file tree?
Is this behavior configurable?

Comment: What do you mean "todo-list fails to import 'input-field'"? At runtme or compile time? Does the todo-list package declare its dependency (and not devDependency) on input-field, in the package.json?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. At webpack build time I'm getting an error that input-field cannot be found.

Comment: Is it npm-installed?

Comment: Yes, as a dependency inside todo-list(but not as a dependency in my root project) - I npm install todo-list - which installs input-field within itself

Comment: Did you configure a custom [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) and forgot to include `node_modules`?

Comment: Oh god.. `resolve.modules = [path.resolve('./node_modules')]`

Removing that line fixed the issue, Many many (many) thanks!